# Why does this trigonometric identity problem work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Why do I multiply by 1 + sin (theta)? If I multiply on one side, shouldn't I multiply on the other side too? Sorry for the weird formatting. I'm still learning how to use MathJax.

Comment: $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}\cdot 1 = \frac{x}{y}\cdot\frac{z}{z} = \frac{xz}{yz}$. In you case, the book simply multiplied both the top and the bottom of the fraction by $(1 + \sin\theta)$.

Comment: 'Cause, $1=\frac{1+\sin(\theta)}{1+\sin(\theta)}$.

Comment: In the future, please format with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Also, if you simply have to post a graphic, please don't post it **sideways**.

Comment: You may multiply anything you like by $1$ without changing it.  You may add $0$ to anything you like without changing it.  When simplifying/manipulating expressions this can be a useful trick.  I say "trick" because how exactly $1$ appears and how exactly $0$ appears is up to you.  You can use $1$ in the form of something divided by the same thing like $\frac{1+\sin(\theta)}{1+\sin(\theta)}$.  You can use $0$ in the form of something minus the same something like $x+(-x)$.

Comment: You post is almost unreadable. Please use Mathjax and take the time to enter the equations instead of a photo of a book page.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying by 1 since
$$\frac{1+\sin(\theta)}{1+\sin(\theta)}=1$$
And
$$x\cdot1=x\cdot\frac{y}{y}=x$$
And from there on you are just rewriting your fraction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac ab=\frac cd\iff ad=bc.$$

This directly leads to

$$1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof above is making use of the identity
$$1-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$$
As we have a $\cos x$ in the numerator of the second given expression (on the right hand side of the equality) it make sense to try to create a $\cos x$ or a power of $\cos x$ in the numerator of our expression, which can easily be done as they have demonstrated.

Is that helpful?